# Cannot publish json message on Kafka topic using ZeroCode

Tags: java, testing, apache-kafka, nullpointerexception

I am trying to create a test framework using ZeroCode for Kafka. The product I am trying to test is based on micro-services and Kafka. All I am trying to do is to connect to my topic and publish a message to it, at the moment. But when I run the test case I get an error saying **'Exception during operation:produce**

**Stacktrace**

```
-------------------------- BDD: Scenario:Produce a message to kafka topic - vanilla -------------------------

27 Mar 2020 10:43:21,531 INFO  [main] runner.ZeroCodeMultiStepsScenarioRunnerImpl | 
### Executing Scenario -->> Count No: 0
27 Mar 2020 10:43:21,531 INFO  [main] runner.ZeroCodeMultiStepsScenarioRunnerImpl | 
### Executing Step -->> Count No: 0
---------------------------------------------------------
kafka.bootstrap.servers - <myKafkaBootstrapServer>
---------------------------------------------------------
27 Mar 2020 10:43:21,681 INFO  [main] client.BasicKafkaClient | <myKafkaBootstrapServer>, topicName:executions.enriched, operation:produce, requestJson:{"recordType":"JSON","records":[{"value":"EquityExecution"}]}
27 Mar 2020 10:43:21,683 ERROR [main] client.BasicKafkaClient | Exception during operation:produce, topicName:executions.enriched, error:null
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jsmart.zerocode.core.kafka.client.BasicKafkaClient.execute(BasicKafkaClient.java:50)
    at org.jsmart.zerocode.core.engine.executor.JsonServiceExecutorImpl.executeKafkaService(JsonServiceExecutorImpl.java:102)
    at org.jsmart.zerocode.core.runner.ZeroCodeMultiStepsScenarioRunnerImpl.runScenario(ZeroCodeMultiStepsScenarioRunnerImpl.java:190)
    at org.jsmart.zerocode.core.runner.ZeroCodeUnitRunner.runLeafJsonTest(ZeroCodeUnitRunner.java:198)
```

I am using .properties file to give broker and SSL credentials. Then send a test JSON. If publishing is successful then I plan to consume from a certain topic and assert on the values - thereby performing an integration test on the service.

Please help me resolving this as I cannot find any meaningful information online as to how to fix this. Much appreciated!

My .properties file look something like this:

```
security.properties=SSL
ssl.keystore.password=<myPassword>
ssl.keystore.location=<myLocation>
kafka.bootstrap.servers=<myServer>
```

My JSON file (Test Scenario, null key is a valid input to my topic) looks something like this:

```
{
    "scenarioName": "Produce a message to kafka topic - vanilla",
    "steps": [
        {
            "name": "produce_step",
            "url": "kafka-topic:my.topic",
            "operation": "produce",
            "request": {
                "records":[
                    {
                        "value": "My test value"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "assertions": {
                "status" : "Ok",
             }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Well, what is the exception?

Comment: Tried opening a github issue? https://github.com/authorjapps/zerocode/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looking ok except the below. You should fix these first, then it will work fine.

1. `kafka.bootstrap.servers=<myServer>` should go into the `Kafka broker` properties which your `@TargetEnv("kafka_servers/kafka_test_server.properties")` is pointing to.
2. The `producer.properties` should not have `kafka.bootstrap.servers=...` redundant entry.

And properties file as below:

```
                          kafka_test_server.properties

# =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
# kafka bootstrap servers comma separated
# e.g. localhost:9092,host2:9093
# =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
kafka.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
kafka.producer.properties=producer.properties
kafka.consumer.properties=consumer.properties
```

That's it.

```java
@TargetEnv("kafka_servers/kafka_test_server.properties")
@RunWith(ZeroCodeUnitRunner.class)
public class KafkaProduceTest {

    @Test
    @JsonTestCase("kafka/produce/test_kafka_produce.json")
    public void testProduce() throws Exception {
    }

}
```

There is a working example [KafkaProduceTest](https://github.com/authorjapps/hello-kafka-stream-testing/blob/master/src/test/java/org/jsmart/zerocode/integration/tests/kafka/produce/KafkaProduceTest.java) in GitHub Kafka HelloWorld project you can clone and run locally.